# R Shiny Javascript Render Plot When Image is Clicked

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have two boxes, side by side, and two images below of cats and dogs. What I'm hoping to achieve is this: When a user clicks on the dog image, the content in each box changes. When a user clicks on the cat picture, the content in each box goes back to the starting content. I utilized some Javascript to somewhat achieve this, but the plot does not render after clicking on the dog image. I've attached some pictures of my app to illustrate the issue.

This is when the app loads in. [image: Cat]

Now when I click on the dog picture, you can see that the content does change, but it does not render the plot. After clicking on the dog picture, if I click on the cat picture, the content goes back (as the first picture shared). [image: Dog]

Here is my code:

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(

fluidPage(

    dashboardPage(

        dashboardHeader(title = "Example", titleWidth = 350),

        dashboardSidebar(width = 300),

        dashboardBody(

            useShinyjs(), 

            div(class = "fade-in",

                fluidRow(id = "cat_story", style = "display: block;",

                         column(width = 8, style = "padding: 0px;", 

                                box(width = 12, plotlyOutput("cat_plot", height = "55vh"), style = "height: 60vh;")


                         ), 

                         column(width = 4, style = "padding: 0px;", 

                                box(width = 12, h1("Cat Test"), style = "height: 60vh;"),
                        )),

                fluidRow(id = "dog_story", style = "display: none;",

                         column(width = 8, style = "padding: 0px;",

                                box(width = 12, plotlyOutput("dog_plot", height = "55vh"), style = "height: 60vh;")

                        ),

                         column(width = 4, style = "padding: 0px;",

                                box(width = 12, h1("Dog Test"), style = "height: 60vh;")

                         ))),

            fluidRow(

                column(width=6, img(id="catI", src="cat.png", width="100%", onclick = "replace('cat_story', 'dog_story')", style = "height: 25vh;")),
                column(width=6, img(id="dogI", src="dog.png", width="100%", onclick = "replace('dog_story', 'cat_story')", style = "height: 25vh;"))

            ),

            includeScript("www/addition.js")

        ))))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

   output$cat_plot <- renderPlotly({

        ggplotly(ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point())

   })

   output$dog_plot <- renderPlotly({

        ggplotly(ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point())

   })


 })
```

**addition.js**

```
function replace(show, hide) {
  document.getElementById(show).style.display="block";
  document.getElementById(hide).style.display="none";
}
```

I am aware there is a shinyJS package, and tried using that. But I'm not too familiar with that. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This should work, however `plotly` has issues with `width` for some reason

`outputOptions(output, "dog_plot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`

Comment: @PorkChop Thank you for your quick answer. Where exactly do I put that? I tried putting it in renderPlotly({ }) in the server.R file, but it did not work.

Comment: put it in the `server.R`